# Zend Framework: Is there a way to get the path to the view template directory?

Tags: zend-framework, templates, path, view

I'm just trying to find a way to get the path to the directory of my view templates using the Zend Framework. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use getScriptPaths() function so from a view you could write:

```
print_r($this->getScriptPaths());
```

Comment: Thank you!

I found out that $this->getScriptPaths() works in the template, but in the controller, you need to do $this->view->getScriptPaths()